# Visual Studio Designer Attached Properties

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, designer, attached-properties

I am using attached properties to allow some design-time behaviour in the Visual Studio WPF designer i.e. design-time view-model data.

The issue I'm having is that when attached property events fire at design-time for my `UserControl`, the type of the `DependencyObject` is `UserControl` and not the concrete type I am expecting. At runtime the type of the `DependencyObject` is the concrete type as expected, e.g. `BlingUserControl`.

I want access to the concrete type as I need its namespace for a convention-based locater pattern.

Is there any way of getting at the concrete type at design-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid not. Visual Studio (and Blend, for that matter) both construct an instance of `UserControl` rather than an instance of your control itself.